# Latency problems at different times of the day

Tags: modem, ping, lag, latency

I'm with Telstra, and basically when it's early in the morning I get 190 ping the average for me, but when it passes 11-12am the ping slowly raises, by 3pm I'm stuck with 300 ping and up, it doesn't go away till 11-12pm.

I know it's not off peak, because my plan doesn't have that. I was wondering what causes this, could be my area, modem, wiring, or non of the above.

Comment: WLAN? If yes, change the encryption-key and see if that helps. Also, check your plan, there are plans which only tell you the maximum bandwidth you get and that it is "shared", meaning there's one node for many peers. If one of those peers causes high traffic, it will slow down everyone else in the house/street/block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the number of devices connected for your area. In the early morning people usually sleep; then everyone use the internet connection until 12 pm.

Your provider should increase the capacity of the network in your area..

Answer (score 0):

You internet service provider gateway can handle constant number of request per second, so in some hours of day u may see that your ping time increased, this is because of in that time there are more internet users from this ISP that sending request to gateway, therefore this high number of requests exceed the number of requests that your ISP gateway can handle. so some of the request included your ping request should be remains in gateway queue and this may cause some delay in answering these request and finally it can increase the ping time. From this point of view we can say that your ISP has too many requests in 11 AM to 11 pm.